# Firebase callable function check type of data parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase callable function that updates a user in my database. 
I want to check the type of the object ***data*** I receive from the frontend.

Here's the object :

```
{ "data": 
    { "user": 
        {
        "displayName": "Flo",
        "email": "flo@gmail.com",
        "phoneNumber": "+33",
        "photoURL": "",
        "providerId": "fdgfg",
        "uid": "2",
        "lastSignInTime": "dddf",
        "creationTime": "sdfd",
        "isEmailVerified": true
        } 
    }
}
```

Here's the callable function:

```
exports.updateUser = functions.https.onCall((data: { user: User }, context) => {
  const user = data.user
  if (context.auth != null && instanceOf(user)) {
    db.doc(${USERS_DB_NAME}/${context.auth?.uid}).set(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)))
    return new SuccessResponse<Message>({ message: SUCCESS_MESSAGE }).toResponse()
  } else {
    return new ErrorResponse('permission-denied', PERMISSION_DENIED_MESSAGE).toResponse()
  }
})
```

Here's the function that should check the type:

```
static instanceOf(object: any): boolean {
    const properties = ['displayName', 'email', 'phoneNumber', 'photoURL', 'providerId', 'uid', 'lastSignInTime', 'creationTime', 'isEmailVerified']
    return Object.keys(object).every(v => properties.includes(v))
  }
```

The problem is that:

- ***user.displayName*** returns ***undefined*** => (expected ***"Flo"***)
- ***Object.keys(user)*** returns ***['0', '1', '2', ...]*** => (expected ***['displayName', 'email', 'phoneNumber', ...]***)

I have already seen that I can put all my properties in const variables like this:

```
const displayName = data.user.displayName
const email = data.user.email
...
```

but this is not a really clean solution

Comment: I think the actual object you are receiving is not what you’re expecting..

Comment: that's the problem Mike, it's a current bug in Cloud Functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently a bug that I have encountered with Firebase Cloud Functions, Data from `onCall` is returning a nested data object

```
data: {data: payload}
```

The current workaround is to redeclare the data as follows:

```
incomingData = data.data? data.data: data;
```

It should be fixed soon, in the mean time - you can track it yourself with:

```
if (data.data) console.error("data.data is still a thing")
```